# How to update a row of entries in a database (JavaDatabase) that is connected to my JTable?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am making a program without knowing much about programming... I used some youtube videos to help me.

My program is made for a chef that can edit users & food and gather ratings and suggestions from the inspector. The chef's section of editing users' details works.

However, the inspector's rating does not as it throws an error: SQLSyntaxException: Encountered "Vegetarian" at line 1, column 65. I believe it is because of getting the rating value (which is int) in a wrong way...

'

```js
    public void getConnection(){
    try{
        myconObj = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1327/MyApp", "Me", "Me");
        mystatObj=myconObj.createStatement();
        myresObj=mystatObj.executeQuery("Select * from Me.Food");
        tableRateFood.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(myresObj));
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
            String sql = "update Me.Food set Name = '" + nameText.getText()
                    + "',Type = '" + typeText.getText() 
                    + "', Rating = '" + ratingText.getText()
                    + ", 'Vegetarian = '" + vegetarianText.getText() 
                    + "', ShownOnMenu = '" + showText.getText() 
                    + "' where Id = " + idText.getText(); 
            //tried the following... did not work either
            /*+ " Rating = " + Integer.parseInt(ratingText.getText()));*/ 
            Statement update= myconObj.createStatement();
            update.executeUpdate(sql);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated successfully!");
        }
        catch(SQLException E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
        getConnection();
    }
```

Comment: Hello, can you [edit] your question and include your code in text-form instead of pictures of your code?

Comment: Done! Please have a look!

Comment: Hello again. May I point out that your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)? It is best to [use prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). This sidesteps the whole SQL Injection issue.

Comment: I understand that using prepared statements is better but I am not very experienced in computer science, could you please elaborate by helping me input my values?

Comment: The links I included are very newbie-friendly. I cannot elaborate in the space of this comment section. Do some research and if you have any problems with that, you can always [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot a quote in `", 'Vegetarian = '"`

Talking about building query strings, you should avoid `+`-ing values and rely on [prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) with sql parameters instead. Allows the database to cache the query and avoids sql injection attacks. And spares you formatting headache, think about date values.

Comment: I think, that's your job, not mine. Well, check out the provided links and do as described there. Ah, and try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=columns+with+'INTEGER'+cannot+contain+'CHAR').

Comment: Ok I will try my best!